# utf8 encoding in Perl and MySql

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

my database (MySql) has a utf8_general collation. I am accessing data from database and showing a webpage (developed in Perl), it is showing Swedish characters (ä,å,ö) with a different characters. I checked in Mysql database, there I can see the data with ä,å,ö characters in it. It seems, there is a encoding problem while accessing data. While connecting to database, used following code

```
my($dbh) = DBI->connect($config{'dbDriver'},$config{'dbUser'},$config{'dbPass'}) or die "Kunde inte ansluta till $config{'dataSource'}: " . $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do('set names utf8');
```

Comment: "there is some problem while accessing that data" is not an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: I mean, there is some encoding problem while accessing data. I updated my question as well.

Comment: How exactly is it showing the characters? What encoding is your web page?

Comment: I am using utf8 in my webpage. "use encoding qw(utf8);
use open qw(:std);
use Encode qw/is_utf8 decode/; " and characters are rendering as "������?"

Comment: Then you're indeed getting the data in the wrong format from the DB (possibly ISO-8859-1)

Comment: @Pekka thanks for your pointer. I checked everywhere in my code and check database as well. Database is in utf8-default collation and don't see any ISO-8859-1 encoding in code.

Comment: DBD::mysql mentions, that mysql_enable_utf8 option should be used in connect call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If each ä/å/ö is being represented in the output by two bytes, then it's also possible that you may be double-encoding the characters.  (Given that the question already shows you doing `$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;`, I suspect that this is the most likely case.)  Another possibility, given that you're displaying this on a web page, is that the page may not be specifying that the charset is UTF-8 in its `<head>` and the browser could be guessing incorrectly at the character encoding it uses.

Take a close look at your webapp framework, templating system, etc. to ensure that the values are only being encoded once between when they're retrieved from the database and when they reach the user's browser.  Many frameworks/template engines (such as the combination of Dancer and TT that I normally use) will handle output encoding automatically if you configure them correctly, which means that the data will be double-encoded if it's explicitly encoded prior to being output.

Comment: I was encoding two times. I removed it and working now !! thanks a lot  !! :)

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `mysql_enable_utf8` on connection:

```
 my($dbh) = DBI->connect(
     'dbi:mysql:test',
     'user',
     'password',
     {
         mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
     }      
);
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I tried mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 but it problem not solved.

Comment: @dotnetrocks: it solved problem you stated in your question. If you had problems with encoding on webpages, you should take care about IO and proper headers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Charset to utf8 in your connection!

```
charset = utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complet spec :

http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.038/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#mysql_enable_utf8

> Additionally, turning on this flag tells MySQL that incoming data should be treated as UTF-8. This will only take effect if used as part
>   of the call to connect(). If you turn the flag on after connecting,
>   you will need to issue the command SET NAMES utf8 to get the same
>   effect.